# Netgear FS726TP Internal VLAN

Tags: vlan, netgear, trunk

I have some Netgear FS726TP switches that are tied to a core switch using VLAN trunking. I have the switch split up so that certain ports are on certain VLANs, but we also have an "administrative" VLAN to access management interfaces for various network devices which is separate from the rest of the LAN VLANs.

I cannot for the life of me find any information on whether or not it is possible to set the VLAN for the Netgear's management interface. Has anyone had any success in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured out that this is **not** possible. There is also a FS748TPS switch involved and in its management interface, it has an explicit option to set the "management interface VLAN".

That's a drag. So much for keeping it nice and tidy!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with that particular switch but I skimmed through the manual and didn't see anything that looked like what you want. Some ideas though:

- Can you test whether maybe the switch is accessible on all VLANs? This definitely wouldn't be a standard behavior but could be possible. Change the IP to be on the subnet of one of the other VLANs and see if you can connect on that VLAN
- On the VLAN configuration page, is there anything about the "Default" VLAN? On Cisco's this is the VLAN that is untagged on all ports by default, usually VLAN 1.

Comment: I will give that a try, though I think I just figured something else out.

Comment: Netgear stackable switches got default vlan 1.